# $\Gamma$ is a path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $\Gamma$ be a [Moore plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane).

> Q. Is $\Gamma$ is a path connected?

We know $\Gamma$ is connected because $$\overline {\mathbb R\times(0,\infty)}=\mathbb R\times [0,\infty)$$ Also, $\mathbb R\times (0,\infty)$ is path connected as open connected set and $$\Gamma=\mathbb R\times (0,\infty)\cup \mathbb R\times \{0\}$$ but again $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ is not a path connected as discrete subspace in $\Gamma.$ I think I must use the definition. Any idea?

Comment: It's pretty easy to show two points in $\Bbb R \times \{0\}$ are always in the same path-component. And that suffices.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thank you but your comment is not clear to me. $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$ is not a path connected as a subspace since it is not connected. Right? So, what did you try to explain in your previous comment, please?

Comment: you can go up from such a point using a basic neighbourhood via a path first. Then connect via the upper half plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in \Bbb R$ and $t\in [0,1]$ let $f_x(t)=(x,t)\in\Gamma.$

Let $B$ be the usual base (basis) for $\Gamma,$ i.e. open disks in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^+$ that are not tangent to $\Bbb R\times \{0\},$ along with $D\cup \{p\}$ when $D$ is an open disk in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^+$ that's tangent at $p$ to $\Bbb R\times \{0\}$.

Show that if $b\in B$ then $f_x^{-1}b,\;$ i.e. $f_x^{-1}(\,b\cap (\{x\}\times [0,1])\,),$ is open in the space $[0,1].$ So $f_x$ is continuous. So any point $(x,0)$ in $\Bbb R\times \{0\}$ is path-connected to a point $(x,1)$ in the path-connected subspace $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^+.$ (Note that the topology on $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^+$ as a subspace of $\Gamma$ is just the usual standard topology as a subspace of the real plane.)

Comment: Danielwainfleet,  your ideas to connect each point on x-axis with point $(x,1)$. How about the if two points are on the x-axis.

Comment: To get from (x,0) to (y,0), take a path from (x,0) to (x,1) to (y,1) to (y,0).